# Does mayavi supports parallel visualization?

Tags: mayavi, mayavi.mlab

Does Mayavi support parallel visualization?

I have two tasks:

1. I need to visualize the very large dataset
2. Need to speed up the regular visualization.

I have checked Mayavi's documents but was not able to get any clue. So I checked the ParaView guide. It supports parallel processing by starting the pvserver and mentioning the number of processors.